# Gantt chart with milliseconds

Tags: fusioncharts

What is the format for representing milliseconds in **fusioncharts gantt chart**.

I found date format as mm/dd/yyyy and time format as hh:mn:ss but could not find the format for milliseconds.

Any help will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try the standard one :

> hh:mn:ss.fffffff

[DateTime format](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: I tried but the tooltip shows as value.ffff ,i.e , for 32ms it shows 0:0:0.32.ffffff

Comment: You can maybe have only 2 digits for ms. try hh:mm:ss.ff

Answer (score 0):

The time always needs to be in hh:mn:ss format in 24 hour format. It does not accept milliseconds in the time format.